# Assign row numbers in pandas dataframe but starting from 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
data = [291.79, 499.31, 810.93, 1164.25]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Onset'])
```

How can I assign 'row numbers' to each row such that each row is numbered in ascending order **starting from 1**?

The output should look like this:

```
data = [291.79, 499.31, 810.93, 1164.25]
TR = [1,2,3,4]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Onset'])
df['TR'] = TR
```

Thank you!

Comment: `df['TR'] = range(1, len(df)+1)`

Comment: Or `df['TR'] = df.index + 1`